# Retry on SFTP Permission errors

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am maintaining an existing Spring Integration application which is polling a third-party SFTP server for files. It occasionally throws permission or 'not found' errors, which I suspect are caused by transient problems at the remote end. I would like the application to retry on getting these errors, as it will probably resolve the issue. (I also have a requirement to "retry on any problems", which should cover this case.)

e.g.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to read file mypath/myfile.csv; nested exception is 3: Permission denied
at [snip]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying from remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to read file mypath/myfile.csv; nested exception is 3: Permission denied
at [snip] 
Caused by: 3: Permission denied
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846) [snip]
```

After extensive googling and going round in circles, I am still unable to figure out how to do this with Spring Integration. Here is the existing config:

```
<bean id="myAcceptOnceFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="myLocalFileStore"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" name="prefix" value="myprefix_"/>
    <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myCompositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="myprefix" />
            </bean>
            <ref bean="myAcceptOnceFilter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="myInboundChannel"
            session-factory="mySftpSessionFactory"
            channel="myDownstreamChannel"
            remote-directory="blah"
            filter="myCompositeFilter"
            local-directory="blah"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="-1">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
    </int:poller>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

**EDIT: I think the problem lies in myCompositeFilter. It doesn't look like rollback() is being called inside myAcceptOnceFilter when the exception is thrown. If I simply use myAcceptOnceFilter without the composite then the code works as intended (i.e. rollback() is called). Question is now: how do I continue to use a CompositeFilter which calls rollback on all its children?**

I've looked into putting a retry adapter inside the poller (EDIT: I now know this is irrelevant):

```
<bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice"/>

<int:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="-1">
    <int:advice-chain>
        <tx:advice transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
        <int:ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
    </int:advice-chain>
</int:poller>
```

...but this throws a warning that

```
This advice org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice can only be used for MessageHandlers
```

In short, I'm stuck. Any help on getting it to retry on this kind of sftp exception would be very gratefully received. Thanks!

EDIT: Added in mention of SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.
EDIT: Added discussion of CompositeFileLIstFilter, which now looks like the location of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retry advice is for consuming endpoints (push-retrying).

It's not clear why you need to add retry here - the poller will inherently retry on the the next poll.

Comment: Thanks for replying - fair point. myFilter above includes SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter (will edit to mention this); if I remove this then I get the retry behaviour as you describe. Maybe my question should be how not to mark the file as downloaded in the PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore on the first few failed tries.

Comment: OK I've dug in a long way here and I think the problem is with a CompositeFileListFilter not invoking rollback on all its composites for some reason; not sure how to fix this beyond implementing a custom FileListFilter class, hints welcomed.

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? The `CompositeFileListFilter` was made reversible in [4.2.1 and 4.1.7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1579).

Comment: 4.1.6. Wonderful :-/ Upgrade to 4.1.8 solves the immediate issue, thanks very much. I don't see an easy way to cap the number of retries but I can work around this.